# How to use RazorPDF in Umbraco 4.11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, razor, umbraco, razorpdf

I'm using Umbraco 4.11.8 and want to create a PDF.
I have HTML code, that should be downloadable as a PDF

I found a package *RazorPDF*, which works perfectly in a MVC sample.

But when I try it in Umbraco, I don't know how to get it.

Do I need a SurfaceController or anything else.

If yes, how do I say Umbraco to use my (Surface)Controller?

Answer (score 0):

The best place to start for what you need is here: http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/

But no, strictly speaking you don't need a SurfaceController. You would only need one if you wanted to access the Umbraco context for the requests you are making via the controller.

So if you just want to have a controller serve up your PDF, you can have a standard controller implementation. You will have to adjust your routes for this though, and this is all covered in the Umbraco documentation above.

**Edit:**

You'll need a route like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PdfRazor",
    url: "PdfCreator/{action}"
);
```

You will also need to add the path to the Web.config for Umbraco to ignore, e.g:

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install,~/pdfcreator" />
```

Comment: I worked with Umbraco in the _WebForms-Mode_. Do I have to change it in the UmbracoSettings.config? I was also confused because I didn't found a Global.asax.cs.

Comment: You can still use a controller when in web forms mode. Just imagine that this isn't an Umbraco site, but a standard webforms project. Provided you set a route, you can use a controller. Wrt the global.asax.cs, you may need to create one and have it inherit from `UmbracoApplication`. Then the Global.asax file can inherit from your global class.

Comment: Does the controller have to be in a _Controllers_ folder? Now I'm getting an 404 error from IIS and not from Umbraco anymore.

Comment: What IIS are you using? 6 or 7+. If 6, you'll need to set up a wild card mapping. Not so if you're using IIS7+

Comment: Now i changed the project into web forms mode and made a template (Test) which is in the view folder now. I can call it with www.url.com/test. Then I have tried to hijack this route. I took this tutorial http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers. I created a controller named TestController and tried to show the view as PDF with RazorPDF, but it still shows me the normal HTML template so I can't get into the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I put it as answer so it's more readable. Feel free to edit.

I don't find my fault or what I'm missing.

My Controller signature is like this: `public class PdfCreatorController : Controller`

and the method, which I want to call is called `public override ActionResult Pdf()`.

My routing:

```
RouteTable.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );`.
```

Then I try to call my controller like `www.url.com/PdfCreator/Pdf`.